# If statement with 1 condition has 4 branches in code coverage tool

Tags: c++, unit-testing, code-coverage

While looking at the following [results from codecov](https://codecov.io/gh/pamarcos/gencc/src/e0c695ec0f8f8d9774a3daaa301e8d0cc6d7916f/src/builder.cpp) I noticed that the `if` statement at line 40 has 4 branches instead of 2 as I was expecting.

```
if (!m_helper->getCwd(cwd)) {
    throw std::runtime_error("Couldn't get current working dir");
}
```

Has this anything to do with the exception?
How do I get full coverage of that statement with the unit tests?

You can find the project here: https://github.com/pamarcos/gencc/

**Edit**:

The code of `getCwd` is available [here](https://github.com/pamarcos/gencc/blob/master/src/helper.cpp#L59):

```
bool HelperImpl::getCwd(std::string& str)
{
    if (getcwd(reinterpret_cast<char*>(m_buffer.data()), sizeof(m_buffer)) == nullptr) {
        str.clear();
        return false;
    }
    str = reinterpret_cast<char*>(m_buffer.data());
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Is `getCWD()` possibly inlined such that its internal condition got expanded?